# Possible to have half of text drawn to canvas a different color?

Tags: java, android, canvas, watch

In my watch face I am making I create Paint objects for drawing my text, which are then passed to the Canvas class drawText() method.

Say I want to draw the time, 0841. Is it possible for me to draw the first two digits in one colors, and the last two digits in a different color?

For example, I want to draw the first too digits in color white, and have the last two drawn in the color red. I could probably create separate Paint objects and draw the minute/hour separate, but I'm afraid that it would get tedious with the alignment if I go that way.

I've attached an image to demonstrate what I mean.

```
Paint hourPaint = new Paint();
hourPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
hourPaint.setTextSize(timeSize);
```

[image]

Comment: read about `Spannable`, you need to use `ForegroundColorSpan` and `StyleSpan` as i see that "41" is also shown in bold

Comment: I've never heard of that, would this be a conceivable option to use on Android Wear devices?

Comment: sure, why not? wear has it all, red and bold just in two lines of code, compare it to the code below...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite simple to achieve that.
You're on the right track.
Try something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class ClockView extends View {
private Paint mHourPaint;
private Paint mMinutePaint;
private float mFontSize;

public ClockView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ClockView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ClockView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    mFontSize = 92.0f;

    mHourPaint = new Paint();
    mHourPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mHourPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mHourPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mHourPaint.setTextSize(mFontSize);

    mMinutePaint = new Paint();
    mMinutePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mMinutePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mMinutePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mMinutePaint.setTextSize(mFontSize);
    mMinutePaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    String hourText = "08";
    String minuteText = "41";

    final float x = mHourPaint.measureText(hourText);
    canvas.drawText(hourText, 0, mFontSize, mHourPaint);

    canvas.drawText(minuteText, x, mFontSize, mMinutePaint);
}
}
```

Be sure to also account for the viewport size -- you don't want to be drawing something that exceeds the bounds of your view.

Comment: Yep, this is what I was thinking as well. I thought there might have been a way already to do this rather than reinventing it.

Comment: It depends what your goal is. If you're looking for a highly customizable view where you want to throw in maybe a custom animation (card flip of a digit when the time changes for example...) then this is a good place to start.
However, if you want something very static -- I would just declare a custom view in xml -- LinearLayout with orientation horizontal and two TextView child elements -- one for hour and one for minute and declar the styles as you wish.

Comment: Using XML in Android Wear watch faces was before the official API existed. Now it is recommended to use the classes provided in the wearable support library.